# Why does my 1D Bayesian CNN, made by replacing the convolution and dense layers with Convolution1DFlipout and DenseFlipout of a working CNN not train?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, bayesian-networks, bayesian-deep-learning

I have a CNN model that classifies waveforms (of the shape (601,3), where 601 is the number of timesteps while 3 is the number of channels) into noise or signal. It is as follows:

```
# imports
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

random_seed = 42

tf.random.set_seed(random_seed)

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=(601, 3)),  # Input shape for 1D data
    layers.Conv1D(32, kernel_size=16, activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=16, activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv1D(128, kernel_size=16, activation='relu'),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(80, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(80, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

num_epochs = 40
batch_size = 48

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train_encoded, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test_encoded), verbose=2)

# X_train shape: (num_train_samples,601,3)
# X_test shape: (num_test_samples,601,3)
# y_train_encoded shape: (num_train_samples,2)
# y_test_encoded shape: (num_test_samples,2)
```

The above model runs finely converges at the 12th epoch and gives an accuracy of over 99% after training over all the epochs.

The problem arises when I try to convert the above CNN to a Bayesian CNN by replacing the Conv1D and Dense layers with Convolution1DFlipout and DenseFlipout layers respectively.

```
# imports
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tfd = tfp.distributions
tfpl = tfp.layers

random_seed = 42

tf.random.set_seed(random_seed)

num_training_samples = X_train.shape[0]
kl_divergence_fn = lambda q, p, _: tfd.kl_divergence(q, p) / num_training_samples

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=(601, 3)),
    tfpl.Convolution1DFlipout(
        32, kernel_size=16, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn, bias_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn),
    tfpl.Convolution1DFlipout(
        64, kernel_size=16, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn, bias_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn),
    tfpl.Convolution1DFlipout(
        128, kernel_size=16, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn, bias_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn),
    layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
    layers.Flatten(),
    tfpl.DenseFlipout(80, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn, bias_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn),
    tfpl.DenseFlipout(80, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn, bias_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn),
    tfpl.DenseFlipout(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax, kernel_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn, bias_divergence_fn=kl_divergence_fn)
])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model (same as before)
num_epochs = 40
batch_size = 48

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train_encoded, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test_encoded), verbose=2)
```

This model doesn't seem to converge. Could someone please help me figure this out?

This is how the model trains:

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_flipout (Conv1DFlipo  (None, 586, 32)          3104      
 ut)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv1d_flipout_1 (Conv1DFli  (None, 571, 64)          65600     
 pout)                                                           
                                                                 
 conv1d_flipout_2 (Conv1DFli  (None, 556, 128)         262272    
 pout)                                                           
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 71168)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_flipout (DenseFlipout  (None, 80)               11386960  
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 dense_flipout_1 (DenseFlipo  (None, 80)               12880     
 ut)                                                             
                                                                 
 dense_flipout_2 (DenseFlipo  (None, 2)                322       
 ut)                                                             
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 11,731,138
Trainable params: 11,731,138
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/40
3572/3572 - 1937s - loss: 44.5086 - accuracy: 0.4996 - val_loss: 10.1754 - val_accuracy: 0.5016 - 1937s/epoch - 542ms/step
Epoch 2/40
3572/3572 - 1933s - loss: 3.7701 - accuracy: 0.4993 - val_loss: 1.8013 - val_accuracy: 0.4946 - 1933s/epoch - 541ms/step
Epoch 3/40
3572/3572 - 1923s - loss: 1.4620 - accuracy: 0.5002 - val_loss: 1.2377 - val_accuracy: 0.5034 - 1923s/epoch - 538ms/step
Epoch 4/40
3572/3572 - 1927s - loss: 1.1489 - accuracy: 0.4992 - val_loss: 1.0744 - val_accuracy: 0.4994 - 1927s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 5/40
3572/3572 - 1972s - loss: 1.0328 - accuracy: 0.4990 - val_loss: 0.9811 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1972s/epoch - 552ms/step
Epoch 6/40
3572/3572 - 1919s - loss: 0.9570 - accuracy: 0.4994 - val_loss: 0.9243 - val_accuracy: 0.4970 - 1919s/epoch - 537ms/step
Epoch 7/40
3572/3572 - 1963s - loss: 0.9232 - accuracy: 0.4995 - val_loss: 0.9010 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1963s/epoch - 550ms/step
Epoch 8/40
3572/3572 - 1928s - loss: 0.8889 - accuracy: 0.5007 - val_loss: 0.8608 - val_accuracy: 0.4970 - 1928s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 9/40
3572/3572 - 1928s - loss: 0.8496 - accuracy: 0.5029 - val_loss: 0.8410 - val_accuracy: 0.5030 - 1928s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 10/40
3572/3572 - 1928s - loss: 0.8387 - accuracy: 0.4997 - val_loss: 0.8268 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1928s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 11/40
3572/3572 - 1976s - loss: 0.8187 - accuracy: 0.4998 - val_loss: 0.8114 - val_accuracy: 0.5033 - 1976s/epoch - 553ms/step
Epoch 12/40
3572/3572 - 1925s - loss: 0.8262 - accuracy: 0.4999 - val_loss: 0.8038 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1925s/epoch - 539ms/step
Epoch 13/40
3572/3572 - 1926s - loss: 0.8069 - accuracy: 0.4993 - val_loss: 0.8509 - val_accuracy: 0.4968 - 1926s/epoch - 539ms/step
Epoch 14/40
3572/3572 - 1932s - loss: 0.8109 - accuracy: 0.5017 - val_loss: 0.8335 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1932s/epoch - 541ms/step
Epoch 15/40
3572/3572 - 1973s - loss: 0.7914 - accuracy: 0.4991 - val_loss: 0.7814 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1973s/epoch - 552ms/step
Epoch 16/40
3572/3572 - 1927s - loss: 0.8024 - accuracy: 0.4986 - val_loss: 0.7761 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1927s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 17/40
3572/3572 - 1927s - loss: 0.7867 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.7676 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1927s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 18/40
3572/3572 - 1926s - loss: 0.7835 - accuracy: 0.5003 - val_loss: 0.7686 - val_accuracy: 0.4970 - 1926s/epoch - 539ms/step
Epoch 19/40
3572/3572 - 1933s - loss: 0.7838 - accuracy: 0.4994 - val_loss: 0.7704 - val_accuracy: 0.5030 - 1933s/epoch - 541ms/step
Epoch 20/40
3572/3572 - 1929s - loss: 0.8191 - accuracy: 0.5012 - val_loss: 0.7761 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1929s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 21/40
3572/3572 - 1931s - loss: 0.7637 - accuracy: 0.5027 - val_loss: 0.7741 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1931s/epoch - 541ms/step
Epoch 22/40
3572/3572 - 1931s - loss: 0.7637 - accuracy: 0.4984 - val_loss: 0.7571 - val_accuracy: 0.4970 - 1931s/epoch - 541ms/step
Epoch 23/40
3572/3572 - 1926s - loss: 0.7640 - accuracy: 0.4983 - val_loss: 0.8398 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1926s/epoch - 539ms/step
Epoch 24/40
3572/3572 - 1969s - loss: 0.7849 - accuracy: 0.4994 - val_loss: 0.7513 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1969s/epoch - 551ms/step
Epoch 25/40
3572/3572 - 1932s - loss: 0.7741 - accuracy: 0.4988 - val_loss: 0.7600 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1932s/epoch - 541ms/step
Epoch 26/40
3572/3572 - 1923s - loss: 0.8127 - accuracy: 0.5012 - val_loss: 0.7449 - val_accuracy: 0.5083 - 1923s/epoch - 538ms/step
Epoch 27/40
3572/3572 - 1925s - loss: 0.7586 - accuracy: 0.5002 - val_loss: 0.7445 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1925s/epoch - 539ms/step
Epoch 28/40
3572/3572 - 1975s - loss: 0.7814 - accuracy: 0.4991 - val_loss: 0.7599 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1975s/epoch - 553ms/step
Epoch 29/40
3572/3572 - 1926s - loss: 0.7589 - accuracy: 0.4994 - val_loss: 0.7458 - val_accuracy: 0.4968 - 1926s/epoch - 539ms/step
Epoch 30/40
3572/3572 - 1927s - loss: 0.7518 - accuracy: 0.5008 - val_loss: 0.7425 - val_accuracy: 0.4970 - 1927s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 31/40
3572/3572 - 1976s - loss: 0.9064 - accuracy: 0.4973 - val_loss: 0.7523 - val_accuracy: 0.4970 - 1976s/epoch - 553ms/step
Epoch 32/40
3572/3572 - 1926s - loss: 0.7519 - accuracy: 0.5005 - val_loss: 0.7480 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1926s/epoch - 539ms/step
Epoch 33/40
3572/3572 - 1962s - loss: 0.7544 - accuracy: 0.5018 - val_loss: 0.7468 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1962s/epoch - 549ms/step
Epoch 34/40
3572/3572 - 1933s - loss: 0.7630 - accuracy: 0.4998 - val_loss: 0.7402 - val_accuracy: 0.4917 - 1933s/epoch - 541ms/step
Epoch 35/40
3572/3572 - 1974s - loss: 0.7534 - accuracy: 0.5004 - val_loss: 0.7421 - val_accuracy: 0.4970 - 1974s/epoch - 553ms/step
Epoch 36/40
3572/3572 - 1928s - loss: 0.7463 - accuracy: 0.4994 - val_loss: 0.7394 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1928s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 37/40
3572/3572 - 1920s - loss: 0.7945 - accuracy: 0.4983 - val_loss: 0.7901 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1920s/epoch - 537ms/step
Epoch 38/40
3572/3572 - 1930s - loss: 0.7470 - accuracy: 0.4995 - val_loss: 0.7348 - val_accuracy: 0.4970 - 1930s/epoch - 540ms/step
Epoch 39/40
3572/3572 - 1923s - loss: 0.7387 - accuracy: 0.4999 - val_loss: 0.7436 - val_accuracy: 0.5031 - 1923s/epoch - 538ms/step
Epoch 40/40
3572/3572 - 1945s - loss: 0.7480 - accuracy: 0.5011 - val_loss: 0.7336 - val_accuracy: 0.4969 - 1945s/epoch - 544ms/step
```

Comment: You have softmax  activationin the hidden layers, that makes absolutely no sense. And it is different to the previous example.

Comment: Apologies for the typo. I have rectified it. The activation used is relu, not softmax.

Comment: Ok, my next suggestion is that do not make all layers use Flipout, start with one layer from the output of the Model, then two, etc. Not all layers have to use Flipout.

Comment: So I start by just making the last/output layer Flipout?

Comment: If only the last/output layer is made flipout, then the model converges at 15th epoch.